# Allow a span to overflow row in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to do something with my layout where my sidebar overflows a background change.

You can see in the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sBkk/) what I have currently.  I am sure I just have things written in my following html out of order.  I want the darker gray to show directly below the recent posts pictures but allow the sidebar to expand down into it.   I can not just use a background image to do this because the length of the lighter content will change on other wordpress template pages.

Here is the code I currently have

```
<div id="main-content-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="main-content" class="span9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="featured-article" class="span9"><img src="http://placehold.it/715x340" /></div>
                </div>
                <div id="recent-posts" class="row">
                    <div class="span9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span9">
                                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span3"><img src="http://placehold.it/220" /></div>
                            <div class="span3"><img src="http://placehold.it/220" /></div>   
                            <div class="span3"><img src="http://placehold.it/220" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed justo vitae quam accumsan semper. Vivamus varius orci posuere turpis congue semper vulputate eros congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas eleifend magna in nulla semper vestibulum. Nulla a auctor odio. Vestibulum condimentum placerat tortor ut tempus. Morbi aliquet pellentesque sapien eu pharetra. Vivamus luctus, urna id pretium congue, dui nisi vestibulum nunc, non tincidunt justo dolor eget lacus. Aliquam condimentum, urna at blandit tristique, nulla felis porta erat, congue consectetur tortor mi vitae neque.

                  Nullam pellentesque, velit in convallis sagittis, enim enim viverra elit, ac tincidunt tellus elit eget dui. Donec sit amet odio eros. Nullam vitae pretium augue. Maecenas sit amet nisi ante, quis laoreet augue. Aliquam commodo suscipit bibendum. Duis imperdiet ornare magna, non porttitor lacus faucibus eget. Aenean viverra purus quis turpis fringilla hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc suscipit molestie nunc. Donec convallis mollis dui nec accumsan. Donec posuere ipsum ut nisl ornare eget sodales metus feugiat. Aliquam viverra, nunc nec malesuada hendrerit, velit nisl placerat augue, sed feugiat nisl turpis id risus. Nunc lobortis massa vitae justo fringilla vel condimentum lectus fermentum.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="extra-body-container">
    This part should fall right under the recent posts pictures and allow the sidebar to overflow on top of it.
</div>
```

I have tried to set a float on the sidebar but that did not work.  I am not sure if the way I have my html will allow me to do this or not with only modifying my css.

[image: What result Im getting with my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the row above the extra-body-container try setting it to margin-left: -100% along w/ the body-bg.png then on the extra-body-contain put the margin-left to 50% and the width to 100%

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/3sBkk/9/show/

```
<div id="main-content-container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main-content" class="span9">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="featured-article" class="span9">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/715x340" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="recent-posts" class="row">
                <div class="span9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span9">
                                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="margin-left: -100%; background: url('../img/extra-body-bg.png') #AAAAAA repeat-x top center;">
                        <div id="extra-body-container" class="span12">This part should fall right under the recent posts pictures and allow the sidebar to overflow on top of it.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="span3" style="z-index: 999;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sed justo vitae quam accumsan semper. Vivamus varius orci posuere turpis congue semper vulputate eros congue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas eleifend magna in nulla semper vestibulum. Nulla a auctor odio. Vestibulum condimentum placerat tortor ut tempus. Morbi aliquet pellentesque sapien eu pharetra. Vivamus luctus, urna id pretium congue, dui nisi vestibulum nunc, non tincidunt justo dolor eget lacus. Aliquam condimentum, urna at blandit tristique, nulla felis porta erat, congue consectetur tortor mi vitae neque. Nullam pellentesque, velit in convallis sagittis, enim enim viverra elit, ac tincidunt tellus elit eget dui. Donec sit amet odio eros. Nullam vitae pretium augue. Maecenas sit amet nisi ante, quis laoreet augue. Aliquam commodo suscipit bibendum. Duis imperdiet ornare magna, non porttitor lacus faucibus eget. Aenean viverra purus quis turpis fringilla hendrerit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc suscipit molestie nunc. Donec convallis mollis dui nec accumsan. Donec posuere ipsum ut nisl ornare eget sodales metus feugiat. Aliquam viverra, nunc nec malesuada hendrerit, velit nisl placerat augue, sed feugiat nisl turpis id risus. Nunc lobortis massa vitae justo fringilla vel condimentum lectus fermentum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps or at least gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

looks like (as you said) you just had a couple things out of order

Here is a revised fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/3sBkk/1/

and really it was just a matter of moving your content into the main wrapping element, and creating a row out of it, adjusting the span to 12, and setting the z-order of sidebar to ensure it overlaps.

I'm not exactly sure how to include the code here but here is the culprit.

```
          <div id="recent-posts" class="row">
                <div class="span9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span9">
                                <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span3">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/220" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                       <div id="extra-body-container" class="span12">This part should fall right under the recent posts pictures and allow the sidebar to overflow on top of it.</div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

EDIT: To achieve both the overlapping sidebar and the 100% width you're going to have to get kind of hacky with your css, and I don't necessarily endorse it, but is it possible, sure, anything is possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Yet7/ (sorry its so ugly).

Comment: well... one problem.... the extra-body-container and the parent row are in the container so the background does not go 100% page width

Comment: I made another fiddle. Added an edit to my original post. To do what you're trying to do may take a bit of an overhaul of what you currently have, and im not sure i'd endorse this route because your going to start getting away from any sort of responsive design

Comment: If you were presented with this design...  how would you set it up?  Would you use a bootstrap approach or custom css?  can you give a clean example of how you would do it... I am willing to change my html